# Need help to handle Authorize request for PowerBI web application

Tags: jmeter, powerbi, load-testing, bearer-token, neoload

Tried to record PowerBI application using Neoload/Jmeter and found that this request https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize have many request paramaetrs like below.
[image]

I was able to co-relate only client-id from the home page URl and I don't find other request parameters in home page URL response.
The authorize request should give some "signin#code=" in response, which is passed in token request to generate bearer token value.

When I send the authorize request with all recorded request parameters, it is not giving correct response. How to handle the request parameters in authorize request,to get the right response?
Do I need to pass all request parameters, if so, from where I can get the values for Clint_request_id, code_challenge, nonce, state, sso_nonce, mscrid etc?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI does not support, and actively discourages, interacting with the Power BI portal application through raw HTTP requests.  Please use a load testing tool that automates use of a supported web browser instead.  Eg [Power BI Dedicated Capacity Load Assessment Tool](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Tools-For-Capacities/tree/master/LoadTestingPowerShellTool/)

Comment: This tool doesn't support multiple number of users accessing reports simultaneously and also restricted by system capacity. My requirement is to performance test Power BI report with 50-100 users retrieving the report at same time.That was the reason I opted for a PT tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some values like `client_id` are hard-coded
2. Some values like `nonce` are just random strings or [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) so they can be generated using relevant [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)
3. Some values like `state` should be extracted from the previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).

You can check out https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/jmeter-oauth/blob/main/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx example test plan which bypasses Microsoft OAuth2 challenge, most probably you will need to amend it according to your needs but you should get the overall idea from there